# Gateway software for wifi hot spot

Tags: networking, wifi, gateway, captive-portal

Im looking for a solutions to set-up free wifi hot spot, but not completely open - i want to give access to all customers via paper coupons/codes. Like, each code is valid for 3 hours of surfing internet. It is kinda complicated, so i`ll try to explain the idea by steps:

1. Client come to a place (coffee shop, etc) and ask for the access code
2. Connect to unsecured wireless network
3. Redirect to gateway login page until client enter his access code (if not - disconnect in 3-5 mins)
4. Assign the access code to client`s MAC address and IP address
5. Disconnect client on code expiration time

Another problem is: how to control the traffic on regular wifi access point? I know, it is easy to do with server gateway, but the original requirement is based on basic wifi routers.

I understand, this is really specific project, so i wanna know, which systems can fit this requirements the best ? Any helpful ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got WRTG54 routers, using OpenWRT and [WiFi Dog](http://dev.wifidog.org/) might suit your needs. It all depends on your AP software and Radius server for accounting.

There's also [CovaAP](http://www.coova.org/) that may interest you.

I'll hope somebody will fully answer your question as i am planning a similar setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have seen this type of solution in one coffee shop by my house, so i might go there and try to spy. maybe i`ll figure out at least the hardware/software they`re using.

Comment: dd-wrt + chilispot can be considered too.

Comment: By the way i would like to know if someone could provide some feedback about HotCakes Hotspot solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe PfSense offers a "captive portal" mode.

Comment: Yes it does provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [Clark Connect](http://www.clarkconnect.com/downloads/) for one of the places I supported. It worked well, did everything you ask for if I remember correctly, it was a few years ago.

There are other small linux distros like this out there, all you need is a old clunker of a computer and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hosted service solution for your alternative ..
theres several hotspot management :
- easyhotspot-nano.com
- wifigator.com
- worldspot.net

you only need wr54gl or any router that capable run CoovaAP